# Dynamic Calendar Control - Invalid Property Assignment

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I try compiling the code I get the below error:

> "Wrong number of arguments or or invalid property assignment."

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
    With Me.CmbMonth
        For i = 1 To 12
            .AddItem VBA.Format(VBA.DateSerial(2023, i, 1), "MMMM")
        Next i
        .Value = VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "MMMM")
    
        
    End With
    
    With Me.CmbYear
        For i = VBA.Year(Date) - 20 To VBA.Year(Date) + 20
            .AddItem i
        Next i
        .Value = VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "YYYY")
    
        Call show_date
    End With
End Sub

Sub show_date()
    Dim first_date As Date
    Dim last_date As Date
    
    first_date = VBA.CDate("1-" & Me.CmbMonth.Value & "-" & Me.CmbYear.Value)
    last_date = VBA.DateSerial(Year(first_date), Month(first_date) + 1, 1) - 1
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Code works for me. Which row shows the error?

Comment: Are your regional settings set to USA or UK?

Comment: Regional settings set to Nigeria

Comment: last_date = VBA.DateSerial(Year(first_date), Month(first_date) + 1, 1) - 1 "The error used to highlight Month